# How to continue with next line in a Python's try block?

Tags: python, exception

e.g.

```
try:
    foo()
    bar()
except: 
    pass
```

When foo function raise an exception, how to skip to the next line (bar) and execute it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take `bar()` out of the `try` block:

```
try:
    foo()
except: 
    pass
bar()
```

Btw., watch out with catch-all `except` clauses. Prefer to selectively catch the exceptions that you know you can handle/ignore.

Comment: A better form of bare except would be `except Exception:`, as this will not catch things like KeyboardInterrupt or SystemExit.  So if this were stuck in a tight loop, you could still break out with ^C.

Answer (score 8):

If you have just two functions, foo() bar(), check the other solutions. If you need to run A LOT of lines, try something like this example:

```
def foo():
    raise Exception('foo_message')
def bar():
    print'bar is ok'
def foobar():
    raise  Exception('foobar_message')

functions_to_run = [
     foo,
     bar,
     foobar,
]

for f in functions_to_run:
    try:
        f()
    except Exception as e:
        print '[Warning] in [{}]: [{}]'.format(f.__name__,e)
```

Result:

```
[Warning] in [foo]: [foo_message]
bar is ok
[Warning] in [foobar]: [foobar_message]
```

Answer (score 6):

Can't be done if the call to `bar` is inside the `try`-block. Either you have to put the call outside of the try-except block, or use the `else`:

```
try:
    foo()
except:
    pass
else:
    bar()
```

If `bar` might throw an exception as well, you have to use a separate `try` block for `bar`.

Answer (score 2):

That is not the intended way for try/except blocks to be used. If `bar()` should be executed even if `foo()` fails, you should put each in its own try/except block:

```
try:
  foo()
except:
  pass # or whatever

try:
  bar()
except:
  pass # or whatever
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want exceptions from both functions to be handled by the same except clause, then use an inner try/finally block:

```
try:
    try:
        foo()
    finally:
        bar()
except Exception:
    print 'error'
```

If there is an exception in `foo()`, first `bar()` will be executed, then the except clause.

However, it's generally good practice to put the minimum amount of code inside a try block, so a separate exception handler for each function might be best.