# How to go to next line inside of try-catch block in python?

Tags: python-3.x, try-catch

I am trying to read multiple values from dict (`d`) which might contain or not specific keys. I would like to do something like that:

```
try:
  a = d["a"]
except KeyError:
  pass
try:
  b = d["b"]
except KeyError:
  pass
try:
  c = d["c"]
except KeyError:
  pass
```

but with less code, without writing try-except for each single line. Is it possible in python? I found this similar question: [How to continue with next line in a Python's try block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952869/how-to-continue-with-next-line-in-a-pythons-try-block) but it doesn't help in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You could make it so you have a function that does does the try except:

```
def trial(x):
 try:
  x = d[str(x)]
  res = True
 except:
  res = False
  pass
 return res
```

and have the values a,b,c fed to that function:

```
if trial(a) == False:
 if trial(b) == False:
   trial(c) == False
 else:
   trial(b) 
else:
  trial(a)
```

Another option is to have a for loop that processes a list of values:

```
list = ["a","b","c"]
    
for key in list:
  try:
      globals()[key] = d[key] # Convert the key string (i.e. "a","b","c") 
                              # to corresponding variables (i.e. a, b, c)
  except KeyError:
      pass
```

Comment: I would like to use the option with for loop, but `d[key]=d[key]` line probably doesn't make sense, it should be `variable_named_key = d[key]`.

Comment: I have updated my answer with changing the value into a variable.